# Is there a way to change the language of google's one tap prompt?

Tags: internationalization, locale, google-one-tap

Currently google one tap prompt is rendered only in english. Is there a way we can pass locale to the javascript api so that prompt gets rendered in that specific language?

Answer (score 1):

sorry for a very late response, however I've encountered the same problem lately.

Official documentation doesn't provide direct way to handle prompt localization. The closest think I've found is: [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#locale). With that in mind I've loaded Google client with:

```html
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client?hl=iso-639-code" async defer></script>
```

where *iso-639-code* is desired language, for example en, zh, de, etc.

Then I've a listener for prompt status, if status is valid (notification is displayed) iframe's source is changed simirarly to script above

```js
// initizalization
google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: clientId,
    callback: handleCredentialResponse,
});

// prompt initalization and callback function
google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
    if (notification.isNotDisplayed()) return;
    const googlePromptFrame = document.querySelector("#credential_picker_container iframe");
    if (googlePromptFrame) googlePromptFrame.src = googlePromptFrame.src + "iso-639-code";
});
```

This works fine for my purposes.