# How to change google's one tap prompt language?

Tags: localization, internationalization, google-signin, local, google-one-tap

Currently, Google One Tap prompt is only rendered in English. Is there a way we can pass the locale to the javascript API so that the prompt gets rendered in that specific language?

[image: google one tap example]

```
window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
  callback,
});

window.google.accounts.id.prompt();
```

Comment: I've answered similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947593/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-language-of-googles-one-tap-prompt/76835732#76835732)